# How href works in orbeon?

Tags: forms, xslt, orbeon

I am a newbie to orbeon, xform and xslt technology. I have followed this ["orbeon form"](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/orbeon-forms-xforms-tutorial)  tutorial. Then I'm trying to understand the source code of orbeon community  edition where I am facing some problems -

- from examples-form-runner.xml (from orbeon-forms/src/resources/apps/home/) there is an href attributes as follow -

  ```
  <examples title="Creating forms with Form Builder"
    xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <example title="Form Builder" href="/fr/orbeon/builder/new"                 
          img="/home/images/form-builder-small.jpg" 
          portlet-exclude="true" 
          size="8"
          source="http://www.flickr.com/photos/yakobusan/2436481628/">
  ```

When we click the image/link a modal is appeared for creating new form. I know about "page-flow.xml" which act something like a controller and it's map request to a view. But I did not find any "page-flow.xml" here which map the "/fr/orbeon/builder/new" to a view. Can anyone tell me how the modal is appared ?

Comment: can you specify some detail about the modal, which about you are talking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly simple:

- [line 35 of the top-level `page-flow.xml`](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/f1c93163c48a36c8cbf8c1ab7445d013672dd3a0/src/resources/page-flow.xml#L35) directs the incoming path to a sub-`page-flow.xml`
- [line 165 of the sub-`page-flow.xml`](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/f1c93163c48a36c8cbf8c1ab7445d013672dd3a0/src/resources/apps/fr/page-flow.xml#L165) is the one which points to the actual model and view for that page